# R How to Write Double for Loops and Store Result in a Matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to store result of X[i,j].

X[i,j] = alpha[i] + beta [j]

I tried writing this double for loop but could not get it to store the result. Appreciate any help here. Thanks!

```
for (i in length(alpha)) { 
  for (j in length(beta)) {
    Xij <- alpha[i] + beta[j]
    matrix[i,j] <- Xij
  }
}
```

**Edit: Is there a more efficient way to do this? The for loop run is taking a long time as the dataset is huge.**

Comment: Try ```outer(alpha, beta, FUN = `+`)```

Comment: And it's a typo, you can fix it by using ```seq_len(length(alpha))``` and ```seq_len(length(beta))```

Comment: I realised using length itself is not right!! It is not going through from 1 to length... seq_len would help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loop is providing poor performance, you should try the `outer` statement:

```
outer(alpha, beta, FUN = `+`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:length(alpha)) { 
  for (j in 1:length(beta)) {
    Xij <- alpha[i] + beta[j]
    matrix[i,j] <- Xij
  }
}
```